# Access static final variables on a class in one app, from another app

Tags: android, static, dependencies, share

While I continue to ponder this for the technical consequences that hitting 'compile' generates, shouldn't I be able to access static final variables on a class in one project/app, from another project/app? The one project is in the build path of the other. It compiles but throws a `NoClassDefFound` error at runtime.

Both apps are mine, so I have a bit of freedom here, though I don't think sharing the user id and process is involved here. It's important that the class stays within one of the projects. I'm not looking for solutions like Android Library Projects or JAR libraries.

**EDIT:** After consideration, I'm abandoning this idea since it had a few logic mistakes. What I really want seems to be to let the first app offer some function to the second. I.e. so that the second app can send the first some data, and get a result back. The functionality has little domain related value, rather a technical one, so I'd like the shortest simplest solution.

Comment: It seems to me you have an idea of something you want to do but you don't actually know what it is. Suppose it was possible...what happens if the app that maintains the static variables isn't running or if the user uninstalls that particular app?

Comment: @MisterSquonk I need information on what happens to the static variables if the app is (not) running. I figure that's exactly what I'm seeing with the error. There's a lot you can get away with at compile time, and this here seems to be a gray zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each app instance is sandboxed, so you can't get directly at the memory of another process. Unencumbered data sharing between apps as you suggest would amount to a gaping security hole.

If you need to communicate between apps to share data, look into the [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

From the docs:

> Content providers store and retrieve data and make it accessible to all applications. **They're the only way to share data across applications; there's no common storage area that all Android packages can access.**

EDIT:

> After consideration, I'm abandoning this idea since it had a few logic mistakes. What I really want seems to be to let the first app offer some function to the second. I.e. so that the second app can send the first some data, and get a result back. The functionality has little domain related value, rather a technical one, so I'd like the shortest simplest solution.

There's a solution for that too.  [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)

Comment: The documentation is wrong in that point. Read the `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE` flag for `SharedPreferences`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE You can change data of the StoredPreferences of another applicatio, too, but only if it is allowed in the first place...

Comment: Each application is in its own process, with its own Dalvik VM, and its own class loader.  The code in one package is not accessible in any automatic way from another.  And you don't *want* it to be, because then your app will fail in bad ways if the other app doesn't happen to be installed.

Comment: @WarrenFaith: I don't see how that applies here.  The OP is asking how to access in memory static variables from another application.

Comment: @Ed S. I was just pointing out that the quoted documentation is not true. You can't access static variables of another application with ContentProvider or SharedPreferences. Thats true. Wrong is, that a ContentProvider is the only way to share data across applications, like mentioned in the quoted documentation. Thats what I was pointing out.

Comment: @Ed S. Intents are unsuitable here. I was thinking much more low level, like some call "public SomeClass doFunction(OtherClass oc, ...)" in one app, that the other can call. With a function, I really mean a method or mathematical function treating data.

Comment: @pjv: Why are intents unsuitable?  You can communicate between apps, and you can use ContentProvider to share data.  That is just what calling a function would give you.

Comment: @pjv: A good read, may be applicable here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx (and I don't mean that to be snotty or rude).